# How to specify name of configuration type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two different `configuration types` in `Migration` folder. One was generated by `VS` when I enabled Migrations. And the another one I added for newly created `DbContext`. Now when  in `Package Manager Console` I run `Add-Migration` I am asked to specify name of configuration file.

> PM> Add-Migration AddedMessageProperty
>   More than one migrations
>   configuration type was found in the assembly 'WorkingMigrations'.
>   Specify the name of the one to use.

Question is how exactly I can specify name of property in command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply specify the configuration type name as a parameter when adding a new migration:

```
Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigNameGoesHere addedMessageProperty
```